# How do you restore from a old __jb_bak__ or __jb_old__ file

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, recovery

How can one get the backed up file from an old **jb_bak** or **jb_old**  intellij file.
    I recently found the **jb_bak** of a deleted file(.java) which wasn't recoverable using Local History how can I get this file back to its original state from the **jb_bak**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I finally  solved it:
wasn't able to recover the original file from the **jb_bak** or **jb_old** though.
I downloaded [easus data recovery wizard](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.easeus.com/download/data-recovery-software.html&ved=2ahUKEwis08HJlN7fAhU3VBUIHVL3DD0QFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2ne4QND9alr7Ev-ykGpdkR)

and specified my project's jar production in order to recover the deleted class outputs(since my `src` class files were overwritten already)  i.e.
`C:` \ `IdeaProjects` \ **`Yuppies`** \ `src` \ `main` \ `resources` \ `Jars` \ `out` \ `production` \ `Jars` \ **`yars`** \ ...

`Yars` was the folder containing my classes **@`src`**

*For anyone who runs into this similar problem you may want to try checking the following paths as it applies for your project(my project's name was **Yuppies** ) if the above doesn't work or if you want to compare results above with these so you can get the copy of your file with the largest size/the most recent update:*

> > C:\IdeaProjects\ **`Yuppies`** \target\classes\Jars\out\production\Jars\ **`yars`** \ ...

**OR**

> > C:\IdeaProjects\ **`Yuppies`** \target\classes\ **`yars`** \ ...

*If that doesn't work try checking if intellij built a jar of the original class* **@**

> > C:\IdeaProjects\ **`Yuppies`** \target\classes\Jars\out\artifacts\ ...

*and see if you can decompile the jar file.*

Answer (score 1):

Just change the extension of the file to the required one. If it is a backup of `.java`, changing the extension to `.java` should work.

These files are produced by safe write, when IntelliJ first saves contents to a temp file and then renames it.

Comment: I tried doing that but all I saw was some gibbirish. Tried to view in notepad++ the text that appeared seemed like some sorta indexed file encoding of the original file